# Read External json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How to read external json file in javascript?
I already used getjson, json.parse method, but it's not working.

My json file name is "testquestions.json".

Comment: JavaScript has no native ability to read files. It depends on the host environment to provide APIs for that. What host environment are you using? Node.js? Windows Scripting Host? A script element in a webpage? When you say "file" do you mean an actual file? Or do you mean an HTTP resource? Or something else? If you do mean an HTTP resource, what do you mean by external? External to the site the JS runs on? On a different site?

Comment: There is almost certain a duplicate for this question too.

Comment: "Already i used getjson,json.parse method" — How? You haven't provided a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin Are you sure? JavaScript native ability to read files is[`XmlHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: @DanFromGermany — `XMLHttpRequest` is an extension provided by some host environments. It isn't a native part of JavaScript. https://i.imgur.com/jfpkXyl.png

Comment: 1. $.getJSON does not need a JSON.parse 2. Chrome and other browsers will not let you Ajax a file from file system, e.g. protocol file:///

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$.getJSON( "testquestions.json", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Check out [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: [Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Comment: unless OP mentioned jQuery methods and forgot to tag jQuery (getJSON)

Answer (score 0):

To read JSON file from path:

```
var configuartion=null;
$.getJSON("./resources/js/testquestions.json", function(data)
                      {
                        configuartion=data;
                      }
            );
```

using **configuartion** variable you can access JSON data in JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

You have to read the File using AJAX. You will have to request the file using a get request.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
 url: url,
 data: data,
 success: success
});
```

You can call a function in the sucess block.
using raw javascript:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
 // AJAX IE7+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
 //AJAX IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
     //get the returned data
     document.getElementById("RESPONSE").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",URI_TO_FILE,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: [Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Comment: Thanks Qentin - Updated the answer!

Comment: @Quentin unless OP did not know to tag jQuery. The mentioning of getJSON points at jQuery